# Disable button on sumbit and re-enable after submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a script below which submits data to the server via ajax and works perfectly. What I want to achieve is to disable the button on submission and re-enable it after submission.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_comment.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#new_entry').html(msg);

            $('.textbox').val("");

        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" class="comment">
  <p>
    <label for="comment"></label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Comment">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: and what keeps you from doing it ? that's just 2 lines of code to add in the code you show...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comment').on('submit', function(event) {
        $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user_comment.php",
            data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#new_entry').html(msg);
            $('.textbox').val("");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. user Ajax `beforeSend event` for that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user_comment.php",
            data: data
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
            },
            success: function () {
                $('#button').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#new_entry').html(msg);
                $('.textbox').val("");
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code to following by adding two lines and it will work for you as desired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
       $("#button").prop('disabled',true); // disable
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_comment.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#new_entry').html(msg);

            $('.textbox').val("");
            $("#button").prop('disabled',false); // enable



        });
    });
});
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set disabled attr on start of function (`this.attr('disabled','disabled')`) and re-enable on success (`this.removeAttr('disabled')`)?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').on('submit',function(event){
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_comment.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
   $('#new_entry').html(msg);
            $('.textbox').val("");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to prevent double-posts, disabling button is not the right thing to do. You must always do in in your code, not just in DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('.comment').data('isWaiting')) {
            return;
        }
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user_comment.php",
            data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
            $('#new_entry').html(msg);
            $('.textbox').val("");
            $('.comment').data('isWaiting', false);
        });
        $('.comment').data('isWaiting', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comment').on('submit', function(event) {            
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = $('#button');
        button.prop('disabled', true);
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user_comment.php",
            data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
            button.prop('disabled', false);
            $('#new_entry').html(msg);
            $('.textbox').val("");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable on click event of input. Then enable in the success function of the jQuery Ajax.